# I want absolute atomicity on a single couchdb instance (insert, fail if already existing)

Tags: couchdb

I've come to really love the couchdb style of organizing and updating data, but there are a few situations where I really need to be able to create an entry and determine if an equivalent entry is already in existence before returning to the user. The only situation that  this is absolutely necessary for my application is user registration. I'm fine with having all user registration writes go to a particular, designated couchdb instance known as the "registration-instance".

I want to hash the user_id into some _id to use. Then execute a put with this _id, but fail if the _id is already inserted. I need to return to the user that the user name is already reserved, and I cannot detect the conflict later and resolve it at that point, because the user would be under the impression that they had reserved the user name.

I don't see why couchdb *couldn't* provide some way to do this, under the assumption that you designate that inserts for a particular "type" of document always are routed to a particular instance.

Comment: Are you operating a cluster of couchdb servers? Or when you say instance do you really mean database? (You could probably just designated a separate database for registrations and continuously replicate that database between multiple couchdb servers. Then writes could go anywhere and it won't present a problem.)

Answer (score 2):

If you send a single CouchDB server a PUT request for a new user document you should get the behavior you want already.

If the document does not exist then it will create the new document.

If the document *does exist* then it is guaranteed to return a 409 conflict error. This is due to the fact that you did not supply a _rev property because you aren't trying to update the pre-existing document.

Only when the _id and _rev properties match will CouchDB update the existing document.

You might also want to read up on document update handlers:
http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Document_Update_Handlers

You might use an update handler to hash the user_id and dynamically assign the appropriate _id. You can also customize what kind of error response couch sends with an update handler.

Good luck!

Comment: Right, but in the context of multi-master, the behavior must be different than if we only have one instance of couchdb, correct? There is no way to know if your _id collides with another because the data may not have propagated to the instance that you are writing to (in the multi-master case). Are you saying that the behavior is different when couchdb detects a conflict on a single instance, in that the client is notified immediately, as opposed to the conflict being handled in an "after the fact" conflict handler?

Comment: Yes, having multiple servers complicates things. Although you may find that couch replicates quick enough to not be a problem in practice.  My point was indeed that the client knows immediately if the new document cannot be created because one with the same _id already exists.

Comment: Your last sentance is *only* describing the case when the document with that _id exists on that particular database, correct? You may wish to update your answer to describe the two situations and how they differ. For my purposes, all writes of user names go to a single instance, so the behavior is desired. One thing you forgot to mention, is whether or not we are * guaranteed* to detect the conflict at PUT time. That is, is a *single* instance of couchdb consistent?

Comment: I updated my answer to clarify that I am only talking about an individual couchdb server instance, since your question specified writes to a single instance. Yes, CouchDB is *guaranteed* to scream at you right away if you try to insert a document with an _id that already exists in that database.

Comment: Regarding your cluster I would like to add that writing to a single couchdb server for user registration is certainly fine. But remember that you still have to replicate the new user documents to the other couchdb servers. If you'll have continuous replication for those then why not just let user registration get written to any database? I mean, if you don't think replication is fast enough then you should also be worried about reading from the newly created user registration documents.